# How to get dots on a die in a different way i cannot figure it out

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import turtle =
    
    #def main fucntion

    def main():
    #turtlesetup/ window set up 
        win_x=1000
        win_y=1000
        turtle.setup(win_x, win_y)
        win = turtle.Screen()
        win.bgcolor("black")
        #varabiles 
        ax=turtle.Turtle ()
        die_width=100
        dievalue=1
        x=-500
        y=200
        dotsize=die_width // 6
        #these are my viarables 
        #square loop for the one square 
        for i  in range(6):
            ax.goto(x,y)
            ax.penup()
            ax.pencolor("white")
            ax.fillcolor("white")
            ax.begin_fill()
            for l in range (4):
                
                ax.forward(die_width)
                ax.left(90)
    
               
            ax.end_fill()
            
         #dot turtle what ifs, dots on the die how do i put the dots on a die? i dont know how to it goes outside of the square and if possible what numbers do i change 
            if dievalue == 1: #how cani use a different method to get these dots on the die 
                ax.goto(x+(.5*die_width),y-(.5*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
            elif dievalue == 2:
                ax.goto(x+(.25*die_width),y-(.25*die_width)) #how do get the dots onto the square i cannot figure this out but these are formatted correctly
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.75*die_width),y-(.75*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
            elif dievalue == 3:
                ax.goto(x+(.25*die_width),y-(.25*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.5*die_width),y-(.5*die_width)) #I need something similar but
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.75*die_width),y-(.75*die_width))
            elif dievalue == 4:
                ax.goto(x+(.25*die_width),y-(.25*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.75*die_width),y-(.25*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.25*die_width),y-(.75*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.75*die_width),y-(.25*die_width))
            elif dievalue == 5:
                ax.goto(x+(.25*die_width),y-(.25*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.75*die_width),y-(.25*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.5*die_width),y-(.5*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.25*die_width),y-(.75*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.75*die_width),y-(.75*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
            else:
                ax.goto(x+(.25*die_width),y-(.25*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.75*die_width),y-(.25*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.25*die_width),y-(.5*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.75*die_width),y-(.5*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.25*die_width),y-(.75*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
                ax.goto(x+(.75*die_width),y-(.75*die_width))
                ax.dot(dotsize)
            x=x+ 1.5* die_width
            dievalue += 1
```

#this is the only problem ihave withe the program how to i get this into the square in order for it to output correctly
#my biggest problem is getting the dots on the die is there any other mathmatical way i can solve this, to get the dots on the die?
if **name** == "**main**":
main()
turtle.mainloop() #end function to execute

Answer (score 0):

> this is the only problem I have with the the program

You seem to have *three* only problems with this program.  First, your sense of the direction of the Y axis is incorrect -- you should be adding where you're subtracting.  Second, you can greatly reduce the amount of drawing code by making it *pip-focused* (dot-focused) instead of *number-focused*.  Finally, you have some missing calls to `dot(dotsize)`.  Below is my rework of your code based on my fixes to these three *only problems*:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

DIE_WIDTH = 100
PIP_SIZE = DIE_WIDTH // 6

def main():
    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.color('white')
    turtle.penup()

    x = -450
    y = 200

    for dievalue in range(1, 7):
        turtle.goto(x, y)
        turtle.begin_fill()

        for _ in range(4):
            turtle.forward(DIE_WIDTH)
            turtle.left(90)

        turtle.end_fill()

        turtle.pencolor('black')

        if dievalue in [1, 3, 5]:  # center
            turtle.goto(x + DIE_WIDTH/2, y + DIE_WIDTH/2)
            turtle.dot(PIP_SIZE)

        if dievalue in [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:  # lower left and upper right
            turtle.goto(x + DIE_WIDTH/4, y + DIE_WIDTH/4)
            turtle.dot(PIP_SIZE)
            turtle.goto(x + 3*DIE_WIDTH/4, y + 3*DIE_WIDTH/4)
            turtle.dot(PIP_SIZE)

        if dievalue in [4, 5, 6]:  # upper left and lower right
            turtle.goto(x + DIE_WIDTH/4, y + 3*DIE_WIDTH/4)
            turtle.dot(PIP_SIZE)
            turtle.goto(x + 3*DIE_WIDTH/4, y + DIE_WIDTH/4)
            turtle.dot(PIP_SIZE)

        if dievalue == 6:  # left and right
            turtle.goto(x + DIE_WIDTH/4, y + DIE_WIDTH/2)
            turtle.dot(PIP_SIZE)
            turtle.goto(x + 3*DIE_WIDTH/4, y + DIE_WIDTH/2)
            turtle.dot(PIP_SIZE)

        x += 1.5 * DIE_WIDTH

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT = 1000, 1000

    screen = Screen()
    screen.setup(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
    screen.bgcolor('black')

    main()

    screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

This appears to be an example of writing too much code without testing.  You should have written and debugged code for the '1' die face before adding the code for the other faces.